# How to create a vector of a specific number of Results?

Tags: rust, hyper

I am trying to send a stream of data with a specific size without the content length header. I believe `hyper::body::Body::wrap_stream` is what I'm looking for. However, I'm not sure how to extend the [example](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.12.35/hyper/struct.Body.html#method.wrap_stream) of creating a vector of results given in documentation to incorporate a custom size.

I'm looking for something like this, but I don't know the best way to resolve issues with `vec![Ok(0); bytes]`.

```
let chunks: Vec<Result<_, std::io::Error>> = vec![Ok(0); bytes];

let stream = futures_util::stream::iter(chunks);

let body = Body::wrap_stream(stream);
```

Comment: You might want to try `Vec::with_capacity(num)` and if you want it to be a specific number of bytes you could always do the math with `target_bytes / std::mem::size_of::<std::io::Result<_>>()`.

Comment: What issues are you having with `vec![Ok(0); bytes]`? I can't compile the code to check myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `Result` does not implement `Clone` so you can't use this syntax to initialize the `Vec`.

You can make it work by changing it as follow:

```rust
let mut chunks: Vec<Result<_, std::io::Error>> = Vec::new();
chunks.resize_with(bytes, || Ok(0));
```

This way, you initialize independent `Result` values.

Comment: You could instead use [`resize_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.resize_with) to avoid allocating the vector twice.

Comment: @apilat  Good remark. I edited the code to use your suggestion.